# One way SQL table sync to remote database (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

I need to synchronize a table that is held in my local SQL Server 2008 database with one on my remote PHPMyAdmin database. This can be one way as only the local database will have changes made to it. The sync doesn't need to be instant, but ideally would be able to happen on a schedule (e.g. every 10 minutes).

I've read about possibly using a script for this but I can't find anywhere that shows how to do this. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Edit: The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448195/how-to-synchronize-sqlserver-database-and-mysql-database) is the along the same lines but the answers don't make much sense to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Synchronize SQLServer Database and MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17448195/how-to-synchronize-sqlserver-database-and-mysql-database)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14661501/synchronize-mysql-remote-local-database-using-phpmyadmin