# how to do Data replication on MS SQL Linked server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linked-server

We have created a MS SQL Linked server for a MYSQL database...I have a data replication questions related to linked server

1.Once a MS SQL Linked server is created between MYSQL and MS SQL,if we insert any new data into existing tables of MYSQL,does the data get automatically replicated to the MSSQL Linked server?

2.If we add new tables or columns how to data replication is handled between MYSQL and MS SQL linked server?is there an automated way to replicate data?

Answer (score 0):

A linked server in SQL server simply provides you the *capability* to issue commands against a remote server. It does not mean any kind of replication will happen automatically for schema or data. As to how to actually accomplish replication between SQL Server and MySQL, the question has been asked and answered many times. As far as I know you will need to use a third party framework or roll something of your own via ETL, triggers, etc.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx

[Replication from MySQL to MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455018/replication-from-mysql-to-ms-sql)